# How to split javascript object definition in several files

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an Object View original defined in one file View.js :

```
      var View = (function () {

      function View() {
      }

       View.prototype.SubFunc = function() {

      }   

      return View;
  })();
```

Now I want to be able to split in 2 files :

View.js

```
  var View = (function () {

      function View() {
      }

      return View;
  })();
```

and SubFunc.js

```
      View.prototype.SubFunc = function() {

      }
```

Why it doesn't seem to work anymore ? During execution I get this error :

```
      view.SubFunc is not a function
```

Comment: Why would you want to split up the constructor like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS files are imported **one by one** but **asynchronously** and there is no guarantee that **file1** will be loaded before **file2**.

You can wrap file2 (SubFunc.js) into a **document.onload event** so that it will be executed when other files are loaded.

```
document.onload = function(){

   View.prototype.SubFunc = function() {
   }   
}
```